# iOS: How to take Screen shot of AVplayer?

Tags: swift3

To play videos in my project.I have created Custom video player(i.e AVplayerLayer instead of AVPlayerViewController) for custom controls.The problem is when i try to take a screenshot of videoPlayer it returns black image.

This is the code i have used to take a screenshot

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful!

Comment: Show the code that you have used to play audio/video

Answer (score 0):

If you need to take a snapshot of a view containing an AVPlayerLayer, to use in animations/freeze states, you can also use `view.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates:)`.

This returns a view with a screenshot of your view.
Handy in combination with `UIVisualEffectView`! :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this,hope it will help you...

```
extension UIView
{
  public func getSnapshotImage() -> UIImage
  {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0)
    self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let snapshotImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return snapshotImage
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let Snap = self.VideoPlayerView.getSnapshotImage
```

Comment: This often gives a black image when using on an actual device

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using `AVPlayer` rather than `AVAssetReader+AVAssetReaderTrackOutput`(which can take screen shot just along with playing)

I guess this will help you.

```
if let item = player.currentItem {
    let imageGenerator = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: item.asset)
    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    if let cgImage = try? imageGenerator.copyCGImage(at: item.currentTime(), actualTime: nil) {
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

TIP: You can get that item at you own way. (e. the same when you create the AVPlayer)

The assumptions just for safty which compiler indicates you. (You can forced unwrapping of course)

Comment: this way has troubles with image orientation

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov appliesPreferredTrackTransform should do the trick